# Expressão Regular para uma cadeia de binários que aceita número par de zeros

Tags: regex

Conforme consta no título, segue a DFA que aceita a linguagem proposta:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida é com relação a expressão regular dessa DFA que é a seguinte:`(1*01*01*)*`. Conforma a expressão regular, não significa que qualquer string que venha dali comece com o binário `1`?

Comment: A expressão regular correta para essa imagem não seria `1*(01*01*)*`? Na imagem o automato aceita tanto a palavra vazia quanto palavras com vários 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não, a string não precisa necessariamente começar com `1`.

Afinal, `1*` quer dizer "[**zero** ou mais](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) ocorrências de `1`". O quantificador `*` admite zero ocorrências, o que quer dizer que o `1` não é obrigatório ([veja alguns exemplos](https://regex101.com/r/lwuDlv/1/)).

Só um detalhe: a regex possui um quantificador em volta dos parênteses: `(...)*`, o que quer dizer que tudo que está entre os parênteses também pode ocorrer zero vezes. Ou seja, a regex também aceita strings vazias (ou "nada" - [veja aqui](https://regex101.com/r/lwuDlv/2/) como ela encontra um *match*).

Se bem que [zero é um número par](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero), então "zero ocorrências" do dígito `0` também é um "número par de zeros" (mas se a string não for vazia, aí deve ter pelo menos dois zeros).

---

Se não quiser considerar válida uma string vazia, pode trocar a regex para `(1*01*01*)+`, pois o quantificador `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências", ou seja, o que está entre parênteses deve ocorrer pelo menos uma vez. Assim, a string vazia não é mais considerada válida.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, ficou claro. Porém agora notei outra coisa que me deixou em dúvida. No caso a string contendo apenas um par de zeros `00` seria aceita? Ou obrigatoriamente ela terá `0101`

Comment: @Pirategull Um par de zeros aceita sim: https://regex101.com/r/lwuDlv/4/ - repare que todos os `1` tem um `*` logo depois, então todos podem ocorrer zero ou mais vezes.

Comment: Puxa, que legal o link que você enviou, não conhecia me será muito útil obrigado. Mas ainda não consigo entender muito bem como funciona essas expressões. (Edit: agora entendi, eu tava considerando como se fosse `(01)*`. Desculpe

Comment: @Pirategull Expressões regulares é um assunto bem complexo. Eu sugiro começar por [aqui](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) e depois [aqui](https://www.rexegg.com/)

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado pelas sugestões. Se me permitir uma última pergunta. No site regex101, como represento o sigma? (que possa assumir tanto `0` como `1`)

Comment: @Pirategull Se quer o próprio caractere sigma (`Σ`), é só colocá-lo. Se quer dizer que pode ter um `0` ou `1`, pode usar `[01]`: https://regex101.com/r/WuqtcJ/1/

Comment: eternamente grato